# Unity screenshot error: capturing the editor too

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, screenshot

I'm trying to create some screenshots but `ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot` actually captures the entire editor and not just the Game view.

[image: error]

```
public class ScreenShotTaker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public KeyCode takeScreenshotKey = KeyCode.S;
    public int screenshotCount = 0;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(takeScreenshotKey))
        {
            ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot("Screenshots/"
                 + "_" + screenshotCount + "_"+ Screen.width + "X" +     Screen.height + "" + ".png");
            Debug.Log("Screenshot taken.");
        }
    }
}
```

What could be the issue? How to take a decent, game view only screenshot that includes the UI?

**Note**, the UI thing, I found other methods online to take a screenshot (using `RenderTextures`) but those didn't include the UI. In my other, "real" project I do have UI as well, I just opened this tester project to see if the screenshot issue persists here too.

Comment: What's for you UI?

Comment: Some other method that uses `RenderTextures` didn't work as they didn't include the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug and I suggest you stay away from it for while until `ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot` is mature enough. This function was added in Unity 2017.2 beta so this is the right time to file for a bug report from the Editor. To make it worse, it saves only black and blank image on my computer.

---

As for taking screenshots, there other ways to do this without RenderTextures, that will also include the UI in the screenshot too.

You can read pixels from the screen with `Texture2D.ReadPixels` then save it with `File.WriteAllBytes`.

```
public KeyCode takeScreenshotKey = KeyCode.S;
public int screenshotCount = 0;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(takeScreenshotKey))
    {
        StartCoroutine(captureScreenshot());
    }
}

IEnumerator captureScreenshot()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    string path = "Screenshots/"
             + "_" + screenshotCount + "_" + Screen.width + "X" + Screen.height + "" + ".png";

    Texture2D screenImage = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);
    //Get Image from screen
    screenImage.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
    screenImage.Apply();
    //Convert to png
    byte[] imageBytes = screenImage.EncodeToPNG();

    //Save image to file
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, imageBytes);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it mostly works. The only issue is that my UI elements use `Outline` and the outline values are always their default white. I change them during initialization, but the screenshot ignores it. For now, shall I just change them manually? (The reason for automated coloring is that they get colour from the level materials to match up).

Comment: All in all though, still the best solution I have seen out there.

Comment: And yes, I did file a bug report :D hopefully they fix this soon.

Comment: Yes that. By the way, I checked the results in a 2D app and found that it ain't white, it's transparent. So I saved into a `jpeg` and everything works just fine. 
By the way, I need these - as you might have guessed - to upload to Google Play. If I Google up some phone's resolution and capture screenshots in those resolutions, will that do for the _phone_ and _tablet_ required screenshots?