# Save AcquireCameraImageBytes() from Unity ARCore to storage as an image

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, arcore

Using unity, and the new 1.1 version of ARCore, the API exposes some new ways of getting the camera information. However, I can't find any good examples of saving this as a file to local storage as a jpg, for example.

The ARCore examples have a nice example of retrieving the camera data and then doing something with it here: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/blob/master/Assets/GoogleARCore/Examples/ComputerVision/Scripts/ComputerVisionController.cs#L212 and there are a few examples of retrieving the camera data in that class, but nothing around saving that data.

I've seen this: [How to take & save picture / screenshot using Unity ARCore SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016071/how-to-take-save-picture-screenshot-using-unity-arcore-sdk) which uses the older API way of getting data, and doesn't really go into detail on saving, either.

What I ideally want is a way to turn the data from `Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes()` in the API into a stored jpg on disk, through Unity.

**Update**

I've since got it working mainly through digging through this issue on the ARCore github page: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/72#issuecomment-355134812 and modifying Sonny's answer below, so it's only fair that one gets accepted.

In case anyone else is trying to do this I had to do the following steps:

1. Add a callback to the Start method to run your `OnImageAvailable` method when the image is available:

   ```
   public void Start()
   {
       TextureReaderComponent.OnImageAvailableCallback += OnImageAvailable;
   }
   ```
2. Add a TextureReader (from the computer vision example provided with the SDK) to your camera and your script
3. Your `OnImageAvailable` should look a bit like this:

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Handles a new CPU image.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="format">The format of the image.</param>
   /// <param name="width">Width of the image, in pixels.</param>
   /// <param name="height">Height of the image, in pixels.</param>
   /// <param name="pixelBuffer">Pointer to raw image buffer.</param>
   /// <param name="bufferSize">The size of the image buffer, in bytes.</param>
   private void OnImageAvailable(TextureReaderApi.ImageFormatType format, int width, int height, IntPtr pixelBuffer, int bufferSize)
   {
       if (m_TextureToRender == null || m_EdgeImage == null || m_ImageWidth != width || m_ImageHeight != height)
       {
           m_TextureToRender = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, false);
           m_EdgeImage = new byte[width * height * 4];
           m_ImageWidth = width;
           m_ImageHeight = height;
       }

       System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pixelBuffer, m_EdgeImage, 0, bufferSize);

       // Update the rendering texture with the sampled image.
       m_TextureToRender.LoadRawTextureData(m_EdgeImage);
       m_TextureToRender.Apply();

       var encodedJpg = m_TextureToRender.EncodeToJPG();
       var path = Application.persistentDataPath;

       File.WriteAllBytes(path + "/test.jpg", encodedJpg);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Unity, it should be possible to load the raw image data into a texture and then save it to a JPG using [UnityEngine.ImageConversion.EncodeToJPG](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.EncodeToJPG.html). Example code:

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Texture2D _texture;
    private TextureFormat _format = TextureFormat.RGBA32;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _texture = new Texture2D(width, height, _format, false);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        using (var image = Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes())
        {
            if (!image.IsAvailable) return;

            // Load the data into a texture 
            // (this is an expensive call, but it may be possible to optimize...)
            _texture.LoadRawTextureData(image);
            _texture.Apply();
        }
    }

    public void SaveImage()
    {
        var encodedJpg = _texture.EncodeToJPG();
        File.WriteAllBytes("test.jpg", encodedJpg)
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure if the TextureFormat corresponds to a format that works with `Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes()`. (I'm familiar with Unity but not ARCore.) See Unity's documentation on [TextureFormat](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.html), and whether that is compatible with ARCore's `ImageFormatType`.

Also, test whether the code is performant enough for your application.

EDIT: As user @Lece explains, save the encoded data with `File.WriteAllBytes`. I've updated my code example above as I omitted that step originally.

EDIT #2: For the complete answer specific to ARCore, see the update to the question post. The comments here may also be useful - Jordan specified that "the main part was to use the texture reader from the [computer vision sdk example here](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/tree/master/Assets/GoogleARCore/Examples/ComputerVision)".

Comment: This helps quite a bit, I had to take some of the code from here: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/72#issuecomment-355134812 although it just saves a black square instead of the data now.

Comment: Are you able to see the colour image on the screen with your `Texture2D`? I want to narrow down whether the issue is with the `AcquireCameraImageBytes()` step, `LoadRawTextureData()` & `Apply()` step, or the final `EncodeToJpg()` & `WriteAllBytes()` step.

Comment: @JordanRobinson have you resolved the problem with black squares? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @midnightcoffee yeah if you check the update in the original question that's what I went with and it fixed the black squares, the main part was to use the texture reader from the computer vision sdk example here: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/tree/master/Assets/GoogleARCore/Examples/ComputerVision

Comment: Yes, I have copy pasted your code and I am still getting black squares

Comment: I fixed it, not sure what was the reason, but it works now, thanks!
Still, I am confused, aren't we getting images from AR Core in YUV format (_An ARCore camera image with its data accessible from the CPU in YUV-420-888 format._ as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unity/struct/GoogleARCore/CameraImageBytes))? How does it work with just loading it into RGBA32 texture without converting it?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, but in the [ARCore GitHub issue page](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/72) that was mentioned in the update to the opening post, they seem to use TextureFormat.RGBA32 a well... maybe `TextureReader` actually provides the data in RGB format, or maybe the shader is somehow handling it (check out [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/opengl-rgba-conversion-extensions.12354/) that seems relevant)

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not familiar with ARCore, I shall keep this generic.

1. Load the byte array into your `Texture2D` using `LoadRawTextureData()` and `Apply()`
2. Encode the texture using `EncodeToJPG()`
3. Save the encoded data with `File.WriteAllBytes(path + ".jpg", encodedBytes)`

Comment: I updated the example code in my own answer with your 3rd step which I had forgotten. Thank you.

Comment: @sonny No problem. You submitted before I'd finished typing but I thought I'd post it anyway due to that last key part. It's the same general idea, so all good :)