# ARCore Save Camera Image (Unity C#) on Button click

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I have a similar question like the follow three SO questions:

- [Save AcquireCameraImageBytes() from Unity ARCore to storage as an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579334/save-acquirecameraimagebytes-from-unity-arcore-to-storage-as-an-image)
- [Save Camera image from unity ARCore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674399/save-camera-image-from-unity-arcore)
- [ARCore for Unity save camera image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798067/arcore-for-unity-save-camera-image)

My aim is to save the camera image (without the augmented objects) and the pose of the camera on a button click. Today I tried the whole day on saving the camera image with ARCore. I tried the different approaches from the three questions linked above, but it didn't work.
My C# Script which is attached to a button:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using GoogleARCore;
using System.IO;
public class takeimg : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Texture2D m_TextureRender;
    public Button yourButton;
    private byte[] m_EdgeDetectionResultImage = null;

    void Start()
    {
        Button btn = yourButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    void TaskOnClick()
    {
        var image = Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes();

        m_TextureRender = new Texture2D(image.Width, image.Height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, false);
        m_EdgeDetectionResultImage = new byte[image.Width * image.Height * 4];


        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(image.Y, m_EdgeDetectionResultImage, 0, image.Width * image.Height * 4);

        m_TextureRender.LoadRawTextureData(m_EdgeDetectionResultImage);
        m_TextureRender.Apply();

        var encodedJpg = m_TextureRender.EncodeToJPG();
        var path = Application.persistentDataPath;

        File.WriteAllBytes(path + "/test.jpg", encodedJpg);
    }
}
```

Currently the image I get looks:
[Saved Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9i8O.jpg)
It looks similar to the third SO question I linked above.
So something is still wrong/missing. Can someone help me what's wrong? Something with the buffers?

**Update:**
In the meantime, I managed to get back a black/withe picture: [bw picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVGTt.jpg)
Here my new TaskOnClick function:

```
void TaskOnClick()
{
    var image = Frame.CameraImage.AcquireCameraImageBytes();

    byte[] bufferY = new byte[image.Width * image.Height];
    byte[] bufferU = new byte[image.Width * image.Height / 2];
    byte[] bufferV = new byte[image.Width * image.Height / 2];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(image.Y, bufferY, 0, image.Width * image.Height);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(image.U, bufferU, 0, image.Width * image.Height / 2);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(image.V, bufferV, 0, image.Width * image.Height / 2);


    m_TextureRender = new Texture2D(image.Width, image.Height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, false);


    Color c = new Color();
    for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++) {
        for (int x =0; x<image.Width;x++) {
            float Y = bufferY[y * image.Width + x];
            float U = bufferU[(y/2) * image.Width + x];
            float V = bufferV[(y/2) * image.Width + x];
            c.r = Y;
            c.g = Y;
            c.b = Y;

            c.r /= 255.0f;
            c.g /= 255.0f;
            c.b /= 255.0f;

            if (c.r < 0.0f) c.r = 0.0f;
            if (c.g < 0.0f) c.g = 0.0f;
            if (c.b < 0.0f) c.b = 0.0f;

            if (c.r > 1.0f) c.r = 1.0f;
            if (c.g > 1.0f) c.g = 1.0f;
            if (c.b > 1.0f) c.b = 1.0f;

            c.a = 1.0f;
            m_TextureRender.SetPixel(image.Width-1-x, y, c);      
        }
    }

    var encodedJpg = m_TextureRender.EncodeToJPG();
    var path = Application.persistentDataPath;
    File.WriteAllBytes(path + "/test.jpg", encodedJpg);
}
```

Can someone tell, which is the actual YUV to RGB conversation Google ARCore is using? I tried some, but the colors in the pictures looked always wrong...
Is there an easier way to save the camera image from the current frame than my solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this pretty easily with the NatCam API: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/natcam-webcam-api-52154

There is also NatCorder if you want video

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I bought another unity camera asset (https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/camera-shot-19682) the problem is during the photo capture arcore isn't tracking... so when I start "camera shot" and then walk some meters, take the photo, then I have a wrong POSE.

Comment: Ok. It sounds like you should mark this as answered and open up a new question with your new code and details on the new issue.