# Frame.CameraImage.Texture has no data in Arcore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I am working on a project using ARcore.

I need a **real world screen** that is visible on the ARcore camera, formerly using the method of erasing UI and capturing.

But it was so slow that I found **Frame.CameraImage.Texture** in Arcore API

It worked normally in a Unity Editor environment.

But if you build it on your phone and check it out, **'has no data'**.

```
Texture2D snap = (Texture2D)Frame.CameraImage.Texture;
```

Perhaps texture is a null value.
What is the reason?

If this doesn't work, is there a way I can **only bring images of the real world** from the mobile phone environment?

The real world image is required for use in image segmentation and should not include images of augmented objects.

Comment: I think this issue is the internet connectivity problem that is why it return `has no data`

Comment: Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49580338/9683573